# Paste (Insert) into Label (IOS) only the numbers of String

Tags: ios, regex, swift, copy-paste

I have code to implement the "Paste" function.

But there is an insertion of all symbols and not only numbers.

How can I make it so that I can insert only numbers ???

**Creating an Extension file:**

[Swift extension example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942483/swift-extension-example)

[Past (Photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylUQ6.jpg)

**Updated code**

```
actionSheetController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Past", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string.onlyNumbers()

            print ("Past")

        })
    )



extension String {

    func onlyNumbers() ->String{
        do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([//.,\\d])*", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
            var result : String = ""

            for resultMatch in regex.matches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, NSString(string: self).length)) {
                result += NSString(string: self).substring(with: resultMatch.range)
            }
            return result
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return ""
    }

}
```

Comment: Convert the string to a number and back OR use NSCharacterSet and extract the numbers from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `extension` with `regex` function to get only the numbers of your `String`

```
    extension String {

    func onlyNumbers() ->String{
        do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([//.,\\d])*", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
            var result : String = ""

            for resultMatch in regex.matches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, NSString(string: self).length)) {
                result += NSString(string: self).substring(with: resultMatch.range)
            }
            return result
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return ""
    }

}
```

you can use it like this

```
actionSheetController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Past", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string.onlyNumbers()
            print ("Past")

        })
    )
```

Comment: There are errors: Value of string "String?" has no member "onlyMembers" , Declaration is only valid at file scope

Comment: You need add the extension for String, did you do that? @BLC

Comment: @BLC the method is called onlyNumbers() not onlyMembers maybe is a typo please check this was tested before post

Comment: yes, you need to add this to your project is an extension for String

Comment: I added everything you wrote

Comment: can you post your code updated? you need add the extension out of any class scope @BLC

Comment: @BLC add a new file named StringExtension and there replace the code by my extension snippet and must work, please let me know

Comment: And what type of file to create ??

Comment: did you figured it out? @BLC